# GPIO pins not changing state - unsure how to debug

Tags: stm32, gpio, stm32cubeide

I am using an STM32F072CB. Some of the GPIO pins are connected to a multiplexer for controlling the channel, and others are connected to some MOSFETs. The pins are configured as regular no push/no pull GPIO output pins:

[image]

I am having some trouble changing the output of these pins in my code. I know they are correctly connected since if I set their default output ('GPIO output level') they respond and will output as directed.

When I change their values in the code using:

```
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, ADD_2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET)
```

or

```
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, ADD_2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET)
```

The pins simply refuse to change. Using breakpoints I am able to see the code is being reached, but it is as if the pins are constantly being reset to their original state. How can I figure out what is causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting a pin in GPIO port A but the pin you want to set is in GPIO port B.

This could be avoided if you use both the generated pin number and pin port macros.

Comment: Thank you! Had me very confused that is for sure. For those who happen to stumble upon this question, an example os using the port macro is:

```HAL_GPIO_WritePin(ADD_0_GPIO_Port, ADD_0_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);```